# Getting an error only when trying to run kivy GUI from remote terminal

Tags: raspbian, python, ssh, gui, putty

I'm testing some Kivy stuff to see how it works, and I want to edit and run the Kivy app remotely (using putty).

I'm on `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`

For simplicity's sake, here is the code I am using:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Test text.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

When I run this locally, it works perfectly fine.

When I run it remotely with putty, I get the error `* failed to add service - already in use?`

Comment: isn't Kivy a graphical framework? ... how are you expecting it to run in a terminal?

Comment: is there really a question mark at the end of the error message?

Comment: @jsotola I want the gui to open on the remote machine. Due to the devices I'm using being small and the size of my office workspace, I want as little keyboards and mouses laying around, so I'm trying to remote in and start the GUI from my desktop. When I run it locally it's fine, remotely it gets this error. I understand now the scope of my question might be larger than I intended, but how would I run a GUI remotely, as in, I want it to open on the remote computer but the command to open it is sent from my desktop.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, there really was a question mark at the end. Not sure why that matters

Comment: it matters because it may indicate that the error message was not copied and pasted, but typed by hand ... many times people have made mistakes while typing in the error message

Comment: the information about starting the GUI remotely does not belong in comments ... it belongs in the post at the top of this page .... here is what I understand ... you have a machine `A` ... you want to use any other PC to remotely connect and start a Kivy app on `A` and you want the graphic window to open on `A`, not on the remote PC

Comment: @jsotola the information is literally in the first line of my post.

Comment: no, it does not say that Kiwy should show its graphic screen on the local computer when accessed remotely, not on the remote computer that is being used to start the Kiwy app ... that is the information I am talking about

Comment: @jsotola it doesn't really matter where it shows, I just want the gui to run on either one, so I didn't care where it showed up.